# In my Touchscreen laptop , My Custom Slider is not working in UWP application but slider is working fine?

Tags: c#, uwp, slider, uwp-xaml

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Text;
   using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers;
   using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
   using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

  namespace APO.UIElements
 {

        class CustomAutomationPeerSlider : Slider
   {
    public string GEQBarHeaderName
    { get; set; }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        this.GotFocus += OnGEQBarFocus;
        this.LostFocus += OnGEQBarFocus;
        return new SliderPeer(this);
    }

    private void OnGEQBarFocus(object sender, 
     Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GEQBarHeaderName = "";
    }

    


    private class SliderPeer : RangeBaseAutomationPeer
    {


        public SliderPeer(RangeBase owner)
            : base(owner)
        {   
        }

        #region AutomationPeer Overrides
        protected override string GetClassNameCore()
        {   
            return "Slider";
        }

        protected override string GetLocalizedControlTypeCore()
        {
            return db;
        }
       
        protected override string GetNameCore()
        {
            //My logic on what it should call

            return "value of slider in number not in percentage";
        }

        protected override bool IsControlElementCore()
        { 
            return true;
        }

        protected override AutomationControlType 
        GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
        {  
            return AutomationControlType.Custom;
        }

        protected override IList<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore()
        {    
            return null;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    
}

 }


}
```

**This above code is like I have CustomAutomationPeerSlider slider which is extending the slider **
**Now as all other function I have not added here the main issue is the when I start the Narrator of the Window and try to slider/touch the slider it didn't response but the normal slider is working fine .
Why?? **

{

```
     <localUIElement:CustomAutomationPeerSlider x:Name="Band_2"
                    Minimum="-10"
                    Maximum="10"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    
    utilities:StringResourceLoader.SliderHeaderResourceKey="xper_geq_band_03"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    ValueChanged="Band_ValueChanged"
                    Value="{x:Bind viewModel.GEQBands[2].Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource GEQBandValueConverter}}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsOn, ElementName=GEQToggle}"
                    Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Tag="{x:Bind viewModel.GEQBands[2].Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource GEQBandValueConverter}}"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource AutomationPropertyNameConverter}, ConverterParameter='xper_geq_band_03'}"/>
```

}

For more clarification:
{

```
 protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        
        return new SliderPeer(this);
        
    }
```

}

Comment: Hello, can you provide a more complete code snippet. Or you can try simple derivation, that is, only derive from `Slider` without adding new properties to test.

Comment: hi @RichardZhang-MSFT I have added the xaml file . Please have a look.

Comment: Hello, I made some simple attempts, created a class derived from `Slider` and added some properties to it, and it worked fine. Can you provide a minimum runnable demo for us to conduct further testing? You can upload the code to Github or OneDrive (do not include any private information)

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT run it on a machine which is having the touch screen and try to increase the slider value using touch.

Customslider is working fine but when we switch on the narrator [search narrator in window search box] and try to change the  the custom slider  value.

Comment: Hello, I tested the custom Slider on the simulator and the touch screen device, and opened Narrator. By double-clicking and triple-clicking to adjust the slider value, Narrator can broadcast the content normally. My test environment is Windows 10 19041. You can try to update the system to the latest version, or as I said before, create a simple derivation without properties to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT let me check . Thanks

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT
WE have added  this method to customize the slidwr value so that narrator narrate the vlaue in number not in percentage.:[like : 2 3 not 20% or 30%]

Refer above metthod

Comment: Hello, for `Slider`, you can try [SliderAutomationPeer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.sliderautomationpeer), in the document description, it is derived from `RangeBaseAutomationPeer`, which is more suitable for `Slider`

Comment: OK @RichardZhang-MSFT let me check with this

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT not working
Double tab not working
     I think when we do the automation in customeslider then it didn't work

I use customslider as i dont want the narrater to narrate the slider value in percentage .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224330/discussion-between-prashant-singh-and-richard-zhang-msft).

Comment: Hello, I understand what you mean. But there are some questions that need to be confirmed with you. The "not working" you mentioned in the question means that the narrator did not speak when operating the custom `Slider`? If the narrator can speak, and you are trying to change its default behavior, can you show what you are trying so far? I mean, show the complete code of `SliderPeer`.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Actually on Custom slider when we On the narrator then touch is not working on that slider

Comment: Mean i am not able to change the Customeslider value

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT
please see the attached code